# How do you avoid pollution of Emacs namespace with "private" variables?

Tags: variables, history-variables

Probably it is misunderstanding of Elisp execution model by I think some variables are only pollute runtime.

For example let's consider `read-string` argument HISTORY. Probably user don't need to know about such mode specific variable, especially if there is no intention to share it with other modes...

I usually do:

```
(defvar my-mode-X-history nil "DOCS X")
(defvar my-mode-Y-history nil "DOCS Y")
```

By pollution I mean that `describe-variable` will show them if I enter prefix `my-mode-`.

Should I use some fancy prefix (like two dash `my-mode--Y-history`)? Is there magic `lexical-binding` erasing symbol name but keeping "slot" referenced in function bodies?

Comment: The question isn't clear. What is it that you're trying to do? Please provide a specific how-to question. Are you trying to hide some var names? If so, hide from what & when? Are you trying to delete the values of some variables (e.g. set a history variable's value to `nil`)?

Comment: You might be interested in the various namespace packages available for Emacs, such as [Lexspaces](https://akrl.sdf.org/lexspaces/lexspaces.html) ([discussion](https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/gg1qds/a_binding_based_approach_to_proper_namespaces_for/)) and [names](https://github.com/Malabarba/names)